# Mongo Charts, how to fill in X category axis with dates for which there is no data in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, charts

Im using image *quay.io/mongodb/charts                     19.12.1* to create Column chart from data like:

```
{'date': '2020-10-01', 'order_type': 'new'},
{'date': '2020-10-04', 'order_type': 'cancellation'},
{'date': '2020-10-04', 'order_type': 'new'}
```

When I generate Column chart using dates for X axis I can only see the dates for which I have data but no dates between them (see the screenshot below for example). Can I anyhow add those "empty" dates to the axis using only Mongo Aggregation framework (Mongo Charts allows using either Aggregation or Query and that's it) without creating another collection ?
[example of a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45tVO.png)

Comment: You could try with an aggregation following the principle used in this article:

https://medium.com/@alexandro.ramr777/fill-missing-values-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework-f011114e83e0

It involves grouping by date first, then adding extra dates with $project, $map and $range and then unwinding again